# How to build a class with "generic" type and instancing it to the derived one?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have this situation

```
public class CustomClass
{
    public string stringTest { get; set; }
    public int numberTest { get; set; }
    public (xy) foo { get; set; }
}
```

Which will be my main class, then:

```
public class Base
{
    public string somePropery { get; set; }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public string someOtherProperty { get; set;}
}

public class Derived2 : Base
{
    public string someHappyProperty { get; set;}
}
```

I would like to do this:

```
CustomClass test = new CustomClass()
{
    foo = new Derived()
}

test.foo.someOtherProperty = "Wow!";
```

or

```
CustomClass test = new CustomClass()
{
    foo = new Derived2()
}

test.foo.someHappyProperty = "Wow!";
```

Obviously I can't set `foo`'s type as `Base` and I would prefer to avoid the use of the `dynamic` type, what is the correct way to handle this?

Comment: How does `CustomClass` known what class type to initialize to?

Comment: That's exactly what I am asking. I need to initialize CustomClass with som kind of generic type in place of `(xy)`.

Comment: Like @Servy's answer below?

Comment: Exactly. Can't understand the downvote tho, is the question violating some SO's rule?

Comment: It could be that you're asking about basic concepts on a site where we fix bugs/explain strange behavior in your code.

Comment: Is there a more basic Q&A site in the Stack Exchange network then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `CustomClass` generic:

```
public class CustomClass<T>
    where T : Base
{
    public string stringTest { get; set; }
    public int numberTest { get; set; }
    public T foo { get; set; }
}
```

You can now write:

```
CustomClass<Derived> test = new CustomClass<Derived>()
{
    foo = new Derived()
};


test.foo.someOtherProperty = "Wow!";
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP is after; `foo` belongs to a type hierarchy. I think he just wants to access derived-specific fields via a base reference (see my answer below).

Comment: @dvnrrs I strongly disagree.  I consider your answer very poor design.  Whenever you're checking what type something is and doing something for each derived type you're generally doing something wrong.  By using generics here it ensures that the entire program is statically typed, rather than typed at runtime.  Your answer is basically exactly the same as using `dynamic`, except that `dynamic` would be doing all of that implicitly, rather than explicitly.

Comment: Not necessarily, it depends on the situation. It is often better to use a virtual method to allow derived-specific behavior, but not always. We would need to know more about the OP's real situation to know for sure.

Comment: @dvnrrs That would be another possible solution, depending on context, yes.  That's *not* what you described in your answer, and given the context that the OP has provided, it doesn't seem to be appropriate *in this context*, given that he wants to access additional data from the derived types, not to perform some common action.

Comment: Actually that's could be a solution for my problem (the servy one). Let me ponder about it and I'll probably accept this.

Comment: This is for a web application. I have to initialize the `CustomClass` server side after an AJAX call. What kind of return type should the method have then? (considering I can't have it as a generic method).

Comment: @MOT There really isn't enough information about the context of what you're actually doing to answer that question.

Answer (score -1):

> Obviously I can't set `foo`'s type as `Base`

Why not?

If you know it's going to be a `Derived`, set its type to `Derived`. If you don't, set it to `Base`. If you later want to check to see if it *is* a `Derived` and set `Derived`-specific members on it, you can use the `is` keyword:

```
if (test.foo is Derived)
{
    ((Derived) test.foo).someOtherProperty = "Wow!";
}
```

Comment: I'll only know what type will be put there when I initialize the class. The only think I know is that Derived or Derived2 will inherit from Base

Comment: Although this is correct I doubt it is what OP wants on the long run. Type-checking of this level might be due to a bad overall design.

Comment: @MOT Then how do you know what method to call?